# if a map and its inverse are continuous, does that imply injection?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I've proved that a mapping of one topology to another and its inverse are both continuous.
so since f and f inverse are continuous, can I therefore say that they're injective?

Answer (score 7):

Any mapping that has an inverse at all is necessarily injective. Continuity doesn't enter the picture.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an inverse then $f$ must be a bijection and so is automatically an injection. This has nothing to do with continuity.